# How to call multiple functions from multiple files into a WordPress page template

Tags: php, functions, theme-development, templates

I am trying to add multiple functions to show custom fields in some WordPress page templates.
The functions are to show output values from the plugin [Toolset Types](https://wp-types.com/home/toolset-components/), however, the same principles should apply in the WordPress built in custom fields.

I can show the output successfully inside the page template by using a code like this:

```
<?php if (in_category( 'cars' )) : ?>
<?php echo types_render_field("cars-specs", array( )); ?>
<?php endif;?>
```

However, as I need to insert multiple functions and some functions are common between multiple page templates, I thought of creating a folder inside the child theme and call it `functions-library`.

Then I created a file inside this folder called `cars-functions.php`and pasted the code above in it. Then I went to the page template and put this code:

```
<?php include('/functions-library/cars-functions.php');?>
```

But nothing showed.

So I created a function in the  `cars-functions.php` like this:

```
<?php
function add_cars_specifications() {
 if (in_category( 'cars' )) : [
 echo types_render_field("cars-specs", array( ));
 endif;
 }
add_action( 'init', 'add_cars_specifications' );
?>
```

Then pasted the following code in the page template:

```
<?php
include('/functions-library/cars-functions.php');
get (add_cars_specifications());
?>
```

But still nothing showed.

So what is the best way to pass the PHP functions into the page templates?

Also, if I have multiple functions, is it better to have them in separate files? or this will cause performance issues?

I checked this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921479/include-whole-content-of-a-file-and-echo-it
But it deals with echoing the content as html output, not as functions.

I also checked this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8104998/how-can-call-function-of-one-php-file-from-another-php-file-and-pass-parameter-t
but this one deals with passing parameters to be used in the destination file. I just want the values to be shown in the desitnation files.

Thank you very much for your support.

Comment: The same principals might apply, but if you show code that depends on a plugin there is nothing we can do to help you here

Comment: Thanks @ Mark Kaplun. What I meant by this comment is to "rule out" that this question is "plugin dependent". I am asking about the proper php function to include functions from other files, not how to show the data of the custom field. Thanks

Comment: in addition your description and your code should have ended with a php error...

Comment: you are trying to include a file from the root of the hdd, this should not end well

Comment: @MarkKaplun. I am trying to include a file from a folder inside the child theme. and yes, the error is that the function in I am trying to show did not show. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add your functions to your theme's `functions.php` file. They will be available to all of the templates within the theme.

**`functions.php`:**

```
function add_cars_specifications() {
    if ( in_category( 'cars' ) ) {
        echo types_render_field( 'cars-specs', array() );
    }
}
```

In your page template file and other templates in the theme, `add_cars_specifications()` will be in scope, so call it like this:

```
<h3>Car Specifications</h3>
<?php add_cars_specifications(); ?>
<p>More text...</p>
```

You can also include other files from `functions.php` which themselves contain functions. This makes it easier to organize things. Inside `functions.php`:

```
require_once( get_template_directory() . '/includes/template-tags.php' );
```

If you really want to make an include only available inside of a particular page template or templates, you can include the external file from the top of your page template like so:

```
require_once( get_template_directory() . '/includes/my-functions.php' );
```

Keep in mind that if you do an include like this, you won't be able to trigger actions and hooks that occur earlier in the execution flow, so for example trying to fire a function attached to the `init` hook would not work.

Note that [`get_template_directory()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory) is for parent themes and [`get_stylesheet_directory()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory) is for child themes.

Comment: Thanks @Dave Romsey. I am less than average in php. So does the function I wrote correct? If so, I can paste it in the 'functions.php'. then how can I call it in the page template? Thanks

Comment: Sure Atef. Sorry, but I think that function needs work. I'd suggest doing some research on the [plugin API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API). The `init` hook is triggered very early in [the flow of things](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference), so you never want to echo anything there. (The template has not been rendered yet, so this would be like outputting stuff before your page's opening `<html>` tag -- not good.)

Comment: For your example, assuming the category and types things are working, you can just call add_cars_specifications() directly in your template. You don't need to attach it to the init hook. Try it with a basic function that just outputs a test string, and once that works, start adding the additional complexity.

Comment: Thanks I used the "require" code you provided and was able to get a simple test to show. What I am confused about is: when I create a separate file and call it in the functions.php, do I need to create a function in this file? or just paste the code in it? (please see my first code I pasted in the question). Then in the page template, how to I call the values? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sure! Updated the answer with a bit more info and made the example specific to your use case.

Comment: Thanks @Dave Romsey. Now I was able to add the function you provided in the functions.php, and I was able to call it as per your code. However, when I added the function to the separate file (with or without the php header), when I try to  require the file in the functions.php, as soon as I click "update" the site gives error 500. the code I used is: `require_once( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/functions-library/cars-functions.php' );` any thoughts?

Comment: Happy to help! I'm not sure why you're getting that 500 error. This sounds like a localized PHP issue though. I can try and give you a hand over in chat if you're still encountering the problem. http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45818/chat-between-dave-romsey-atef-wagih

Comment: Hi @Dave. Thanks for your help. I was able to write my first function. I tried the chat but I don't have enough reputation to enable chat.Not sure what to do.

Comment: Ok, glad you got the function working. Keep using the site and your rep will go up. Cheers!

Comment: I posted another question that is partially solved apart from the edit on 29/09/16. Any help is much appreciated. [Question link](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/240762/91570)