# Counting number of posts in a category and its sub categories and displaying result using shortcode

Tags: php, functions, categories, shortcode, taxonomy

I am trying to create a shortcode to display the posts count in a category.
I have successfully done this using this code:

```
// Add Shortcode to show posts count inside a category
function add_count_of_posts_in_category() {
$term = get_term( 7, 'category' ); 
$count = $term->count;
echo $count;
}
add_shortcode( 'show-posts-count', 'add_count_of_posts_in_category' );
```

However, this means that I need to specify the `ID` of the category for the shortcode to work. Which means that i need to create a shortcode per category, which is useless.

I am trying to find a way to modify the category ID part with a variable, so that I can use the shortcode like this:
`[show-posts-count="cars"]` to display the post count in the category called cars. 
I can't find a way to do so.

Your help is much appreciated.

**EDIT: 29/09/2016**
After getting the code working, I am trying to expand the function to count the posts in the child category too.

So if the main category does not have posts, but has 2 subcategories, each has posts, then when I use the shortcode on the main category, the displayed number is the sum of all the posts in the main category (if any), in addition to, the number of posts in the sub-categories, and the sub-sub-categories..etc

I tried using `get_term_children( $term, $taxonomy );`, but did not know how to get the post count of subcategories then add them together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### The shortcode

```
// Add Shortcode to show posts count inside a category
function category_post_count( $atts ) {

    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'category' => null
    ), $atts );

    // get the category by slug.
    $term = get_term_by( 'slug', $atts['category'], 'category');

    return ( isset( $term->count ) ) ? $term->count : 0;
}
add_shortcode( 'category_post_count', 'category_post_count' );
```

#### Usage

```
[category_post_count category="category_slug_or_name"]
```

#### If you want to get the count by name, not slug change this

```
$term = get_term_by( 'slug', $atts['category'], 'category');
```

to this:

```
$term = get_term_by( 'name', $atts['category'], 'category');
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick solution. The code worked perfectly for the slug. When I tried the `name` it returned 0. any idea why?

Comment: You have to make sure that the category name is correct and match an existing category name. If a code you tried didn't work, please edit your question and include the non-working function and I'll have a look at it.

Comment: I edited the question with the required details. Thanks

Comment: Can you try to wrap the category name with quotes and see if that helps? e.g. category="My category name" instead of category=My category name. Having two-word category will mislead Wordpress shortcodes to think that the 2nd word is a parameter. so category=" ... " (with quotes) should work :)

Comment: thank you very much. now it works perfectly fine. Much appreciated.

Comment: I am trying to expand the functionality of the shortcode to count the posts in the subcategories of the main category too by utilizing  `get_term_children()` . I tried to open a new question but I reached the questions limit. can I edit this question, or this is against the rules? thanks

Comment: Please submit a new question Atef, that will be better and comply with wordpress se rules :)

Comment: Sorry I could not add a new question. I edited the existing question. All your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

To count posts in subcategories in addition to specified category, one possibility is to query posts using a `cat` option and count the results. `cat` option queries posts in child categories by default.

```
add_shortcode('category_post_count', function ($atts, $content) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts([
        'category' => 0
    ], $atts);
    $cat_id = is_numeric($atts['category']) ?
        intval($atts['category']) :
        get_category_by_slug($atts['category'])->term_id;
    return count(get_posts([
        'nopaging' => true,
        'fields' => 'ids',
        'cat' => $cat_id
    ]));
});
```

There are examples of querying the child categories and summing up the `count` fields, but this may yield invalid results if a post belongs to more than one of the matched categories.