# Display Custom Post Category Count & WordPress Category Count Using Shortcode

Tags: posts, count

I am trying to create a shortcode to display the posts count of a custom post type as well as standard post categories. I have successfully done this using this code snippet from a [similar post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/240762/counting-number-of-posts-in-a-category-and-its-sub-categories-and-displaying-res):

```
// Add Shortcode to show posts count inside a category
function category_post_count( $atts ) {

    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'category' => null
    ), $atts );

    // get the category by slug.
    $term = get_term_by( 'slug', $atts['category'], 'category');

    return ( isset( $term->count ) ) ? $term->count : 0;
}
add_shortcode( 'category_post_count', 'category_post_count' );
```

The code above only works for standard wordpress post categories, not custom post types. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you are have passed "**category**" in "**get_terms_by()**" function as third argument.

Please replace "**add_custom_taxonomy_here**" with your custom taxonomy slug in below code.

```
// Add Shortcode to show posts count inside a category
function category_post_count( $atts ) {

$atts = shortcode_atts( array(
    'category' => null
), $atts );

// get the category by slug.
$term = get_term_by( 'slug', $atts['category'], 'add_custom_taxonomy_here');

return ( isset( $term->count ) ) ? $term->count : 0;
}
add_shortcode( 'category_post_count', 'category_post_count' );
```